# How to make a reservation system for my restaurant website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have made a website for a restaurant. Now I need to implement a reservation system, where clients will input name, number of people and date  and time. What is the best way I can implement this system, where restaurant workers will be able to see reservation requests.

Comment: You need to try something and show some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask